# EMR serverless- Pass jars in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr-serverless

I'm new with EMR-serverless and I want to know how to pass, in a spark application, jar and packages as for example:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --jars /usr/lib/hudi/hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12-0.11.1-amzn-0.jar,/usr/lib/hudi/hudi-utilities-bundle_2.12-0.11.1-amzn-0.jar ...
```

I want to set when I submit a job but I cannot find a way about how to do it.

Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When submitting a job to EMR Serverless in the console and you want to provide additional options to `spark-submit`, you can use the "Spark properties" section. Instead of `--jars`, you can use the `spark.jars` key and set the value appropriately.

Your Spark application will be a Python script or JAR file on S3 provided as the "Script location" aka entrypoint.

Also note that Hudi is available on the EMR Serverless image and there's some [documentation on using Hudi with EMR Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/using-hudi.html).

[image: Screenshot of Serverless console with Spark properties]